# Fix $u,x\in V$. Define $T\in \mathcal{L}(V)$ By $Tv=\langle v,u\rangle x$ for every $v\in V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Please someone help me with following question.

Fix $u,x\in V$. Define $T\in \mathcal{L}(V)$ By
$$Tv=\langle v,u\rangle x$$ for every $v\in V$

**(a)**  Suppose $F=R$. Prove that $T$ is self-adjoint if and only if $u, x$ is linearly dependent.

**(b)**  Prove that $T$ is normal if and only if $u, x$ is linearly dependent

Comment: what is $R$ stands for? ring?

Comment: field of Real numbers

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

1. If $u,x$ are linearly dependent, write $u=\lambda x$. We want to prove $<Tv,y> = <v,Ty>$ for any $v,y\in V$, and for fixed $u,x \in V$. Notice that $<Tv,y>=<v,u><x,y>$ and $<v,Ty>=<y,u><v,x>$. By substituting $u=\lambda x$, $<Tv,y>=<v,u><x,y>=\lambda<v,x><x,y>$ and $<v,Ty>=<y,u><v,x>=\lambda<y,x><v,x>=\lambda<x,y><v,x>$. Thus we conclude $T$ is self-adjoint. Rewrite this step from bottom to top, we can see the converse of the proposition. Note that it is only happen because $F=\mathbb{R}$ as $<x,y>=<y,x>$ in the field of real number.

Comment: I forgot the definition of "$T$ is normal", if I see the definition, maybe I can help

Comment: Converse part is not clear to me

Answer (score 0):

Observe that if u or x are zero we have nothig to show. So suppose that x and u are nonzero vectors. Use the orthogonal descomposition of u as a multiple of x and some w orthogonal to x. That is to said u iquals c times x plus w with x and w orthogonal vectors. Use the Pitagoryan theorem to stablish that the square of the norm of u equals the square of the norm of c times x plus the square of the norm of w. Use the adjoind or normal condition to show that w is zero.